# What does /dev/null means in docker-compose.yaml while mounting a volume?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

In docker-compose.yaml, `/dev/null` is written as below:

```
-v
 /dev/null:/filename
```

So, what's the significance of /dev/null here. I encountered this at this page: https://docs.traefik.io/.

Comment: It would hide that file from the running container.

Comment: `-v` is used on the command line, in `docker-compose.yml` it's `volumes`. See the documentation of [`volumes` in `docker-compose.yml`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volumes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, in general, the "-v" parameter defines volume mappings.  The part before the colon is the path on the host, and the part after the colon is the path in the container.  That mapping means that the container won't have a file to read at that path in the container.

Looking at the page you saw this referenced, I can't help thinking that that's a mistake.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to follow-up with them.